# How to express the label of $x-$axis as a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{10}$ in the given code?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have this data, and I use this code

```
x:={1 Pi/10, 2 Pi/10,3 Pi/10,4 Pi/10,5 Pi/10 };
y:={1,2,1,2,1};

ListPlot[Transpose[{x,y}],
Frame-> True,
FrameLabel->{Style["x",20],Style["y",20]},Joined->True,
PlotStyle->Directive[CapForm["Round"],AbsoluteThickness[0.05],Red,LineColor->Blue],
Mesh->All,MeshStyle->AbsolutePointSize[5.5],BaseStyle->7,
PlotRange->{0,3}]
```

I get this plot

[image]

**Questions**

> 1- I want to show in the plot that $x$ is multiples of $\frac{\pi}{10}$, either directly in the ticks, or (if possible) write the label of the $x-$axis as a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{10}$, and then ticks of the axis form $1...5$

> 2- How can I add an extra space on the RHS of the plot as in the LHS?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {1 Pi/10, 2 Pi/10, 3 Pi/10, 4 Pi/10, 5 Pi/10};
y = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1};

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, y}],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 20], Style["y", 20]},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"],
                         AbsoluteThickness[0.05],
                         Red,
                         LineColor -> Blue],
  Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5.5],
  BaseStyle -> 7,
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  PlotRange -> {{Min[x] - π/20, Max[x] + π/20}, {0, 3}},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Range[0, π/2, π/10], None}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, with

```
FrameTicks -> {{Union[y], None}, {Union[x], None}}
```

we get

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use the label $\frac {10}{\pi} x$ for the $x-$ axis, and, then ticks range from $1,....5$, how can I do this?

Comment: Would `ListLinePlot[Transpose[{10x/π, y}], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"10x/π", "y"}]` work (together with your style fine-tuning)?

Answer (score 2):

```
xticks = Join[Thread[{#, #, {.015, 0}}, List, 2], 
     Thread[{Complement[Join @@ #2, #], "", {.005, 0}}, List, 2]] & @@
    FindDivisions[{Pi/10, 5 Pi/10, Pi/40}, {10, 10}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Automatic,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   {xticks, MapAt[Style[#, Opacity[0]] &, {All, 2}] @ xticks}},
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 20], Style["y", 20]},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[0.05],  Blue],
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[5.5]],
 BaseStyle -> 7,
 PlotRange -> {MinMax @ x, {0, 3}},
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use the label $\frac {10}{\pi} x$ for the $x-$ axis, and, then ticks range from $1,....5$, how can I do this? @kglr

Comment: Like the second plot, I attached.  Also, I get an extra " mark on the label. @kglr

Comment: @math2021, replace `{#, #, {.015, 0}}` with `{#, 10 # /Pi, {.015, 0}}` when defining `xticks` and use `FrameLabel -> {Style["10 x / \[Pi]", 20], Style["y", 20]}`?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {1 Pi/10, 2 Pi/10, 3 Pi/10, 4 Pi/10, 5 Pi/10};
y = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1};
```

Since `x` values are just integer multiples of `Pi/10`, let the `x` values default to `{1, 2, 3, ...}`.  Use the option [`PlotRangePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) to add additional [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

```
ListPlot[y,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  {Style["10/π x", 20], Style["y", 20]},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"],
   AbsoluteThickness[0.5], Red,
   LineColor -> Blue],
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5.5],
 BaseStyle -> 7,
 PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 3}},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.04]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, manually specify the [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html)

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  {Style["10/π x", 20], Style["y", 20]},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"],
   AbsoluteThickness[0.5], Red,
   LineColor -> Blue],
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5.5],
 BaseStyle -> 7,
 PlotRange -> {{Pi/10, Pi/2}, {0, 3}},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.04],
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Transpose[{Range[5] Pi/10, Range[5]}], None}}]
```

[image]